# How to get the right frequency table weighted and unweighted in complex survey?

Tags: r, package, survey

I'm using `survey package` to analysis a complex survey

The issue that I'm facing when I use this code

```
tab_w<- svytable( ~edu+ smok , design= dsub)
```

The result showed the frequency table of the whole population not only the sample population in my survey.

```
         smok
edu         1         2
       1   26466299  87948351
       2   20898455 102012829
```

This is the table that im looking to do

```
----------------------------------------------
    |     Smok             |  Smok
    | Unweighted           | Weighted
    | Sample size          | population Size
    |   1     |  2         |  1     |  2         
----------------------------------------------
edu |-----------------------------------------                    
  1 |26466299| 87948351    |  200 | 204 
  2 |20898455|102012829    |  400 | 300
-----------------------------------------------
```

This included the whole population not only my sample population. Is there a way to include only the sample population in the frequency table?

Comment: I confess I don't know much about that package, but it doesn't look like we have enough in this question to be able to test anything. Is there a way you can provide sample data? By that I mean fake (or representative) "population" data, and a sample of that sample-population data (the use of "sample" is double-used here, my apologies). Bottom line, please make this question at least somewhat reproducible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the survey package at all for the unweighted sample table, you can just use the `table` or `xtabs` function.

Or, if you only have the data conveniently available in the survey object

```
with(model.frame(dsub), table(edu,smok))
```

As a reproducible example

```
library(survey)
data(api)


with(apistrat, table(comp.imp, sch.wide))
#stratified sample
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
svytable(~comp.imp+sch.wide, design=dstrat)
with(model.frame(dstrat), table(comp.imp, sch.wide))
```